# (zk server push) activate、deactivate can fast?

Tags: zk, server-push

I use Thread Listen Socket port,then i receive data and listbox show data.
But i hava a question,i want listbox add data can faster. Orz

I test Executions.activate(Desktop) and Executions.deactivate(Desktop),spend about 1 sec....

How can use server-push update listbox can faster?
It spend 1 sce,now.

```
Executions.activate(_desktop);
for(Component com :comList){
   Label label=(Label)com;
   if(label.getId().equals("personCountLabel")){
      label.setValue(String.valueOf(personCountInt));
  }
}
listModelList.add(0,MyEntity);
List<Component> comList2=Selectors.find(getPage(),"listbox" );
for(Component com : comList2){
   Listbox listboxTemp=(Listbox)com;
   if(listboxTemp.getId().equals("listenRunnerListbox")){
      listboxTemp.setModel(listModelList);
   }
}
Executions.deactivate(_desktop);
```

(The listbox just let worker can know hava receive data)
[image: insert image description here]

Comment: What have you attempted? Where have you experienced a problem?

Comment: listbox show data is slow(almost 1sec update),i want faster.

Comment: Update your question and be specific. Just saying "I want faster" isn't enough. [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: renewing your listmodellist will render all the data again. Maybe worth to look at that and also see what the ajax call is giving you.